# Cordova: Getting Xcode error "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view"

Tags: xcode, cordova

I have built a JS app in Cordova/PhoneGap and getting this error when deploying to my phone:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
reason: '[<UIApplication 0x100401930> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this 
class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'
```

And it points to this code in Other Sources > main.m:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

As I have understood other SO questions with the same answer, I need to remove the incorrect reference to the view key.

Any suggestions for how to locate the function that is calling for the view key? Have tried searching the directory for the view key, to no avail.

//Xcode noob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller does not contain IBOutlet or IBAction for some controls.

Right click on that controller and remove all outlet and action, which contain warning.

Ex: In following image collectionView and lblTitle contains warning.

[image]

Comment: Sorry Im new to Xcode... how do I get to this View Controller you posted now?

Comment: @JonasBolin You can get this window from right clinking on ViewController.